# extjs4.0 Row grid editor multi select combo showing the keys instead of values when non selected

Tags: extjs

![ I am using extjs 4 . and using RowEditing plug, added multi selection combo box , The combo box is showing the keys instead of the values , But when I select any row it is showing the values , After that when I do some changes to the data in any gievn row, Then the values start showing  .

Also I could not see the checkbox when the row is not selected and showing the checkbox when it is selected .

Code

Model is :

```
Ext.define('Employee', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty:'employeeId',
fields: [
        {name: 'alertType', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'statusCode', type: 'bool'},
        {name: 'employeeId', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'employeeName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'jobCode', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'jobTitle', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'jobTarget', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'vpPlan', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'losPlanName', type: 'string', convert:function(v, record){if(typeof v =="string") return v.split(",");  else return v; }},
        {name: 'losPlanCodes', type: 'float[]', convert:function(v, record){if(typeof v =="string") return v.split(",");  else return v; }},
        {name: 'losLocation', type: 'string', convert:function(v, record){if(typeof v =="string") return v.split(",");  else return v; }},
        {name: 'losLocationCodes', type: 'float[]', convert:function(v, record){if(typeof v =="string") return v.split(",");  else return v; }},
        {name: 'entity', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'locationCode', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'deptId', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'deptName', type: 'string'},
    ]
```

});

Grid Store :-

```
var directReportiesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoDestroy: true,
    autoLoad:true,
    autoSync: true,
    allowSingle: true,
    storeId: 'directReportiesStore',
    model: 'Employee',
    sorters: [{
        property: 'employeeName',
        direction:'ASC'
    }],
    proxy: {    
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getDirectReportiesJson.do?plannerId='+plannerId,
        api: {
            update: 'getDirectReportiesJson.do?plannerId='+plannerId,
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            idProperty: 'employeeId',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        write: function(proxy, operation){
            Ext.example.msg(operation.action, operation.resultSet.message);
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store,records){
                for(var rec=0; rec< records.length; rec++){
                    for(var i=0; i< Ext.getCmp('employeeGrid').columns.length; i++){
                        if(Ext.getCmp('employeeGrid').columns[i].getId() =='losLocationCodes'){
                            alert(Ext.getCmp('employeeGrid').columns[i].getId())
                            Ext.getCmp('employeeGrid').columns[i].getEditor().setValue(records[rec].get('losLocationCodes'))
                            alert(records[rec].get('losLocationCodes'));
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
});
```

![][1]

Combo Box stores :

```
// create the Plan Store
var planStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoDestroy: true,
    storeId: 'planStore',
    idIndex: 0,
    fields: [
        {name: 'planId', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'planName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'planTypeName', type: 'string'},
   ]
});

planStore.loadData(plansJson);


// create the Location Store
var locationStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoDestroy: true,
    storeId: 'locationStore',
    idIndex: 0,
    fields: [
        {name: 'locAreaId', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'locAreaName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'active', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'inclRegAvg', type: 'string'},
   ]
});

locationStore.loadData(locationJson);
```

GRID using all three stores ...

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: directReportiesStore,
    id:'employeeGrid',
    title: 'Employee Varieable Pay Mapping',
    width: 1100,
    height: 400,
    frame: true,
    columns: [{
        id: 'alertType',
        header: 'Alert',
        width: 30,
        dataIndex: 'alertType',
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } , {
        id: 'statusCode',
        header: 'Reviewed?',
        dataIndex: 'statusCode',
        width: 40,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor'
        }
    } , {
        id: 'employeeId',
        header: 'Employee Id',
        dataIndex: 'employeeId',
        width: 50,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'employeeName',
        header: 'Employee Name',
        dataIndex: 'employeeName',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'jobCode',
        header: 'Job Code',
        dataIndex: 'jobCode',
        width: 40,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'jobTitle',
        header: 'Job Title',
        dataIndex: 'jobTitle',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'jobTarget',
        header: 'Job Target',
        dataIndex: 'jobTarget',
        width: 40,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } , {
        id:'vpPlan',
        header: 'VP Plan',
        dataIndex: 'vpPlan',
        width: 70,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            typeAhead: true,
            editable: false,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            selectOnTab: true,
            store: [
                ['SCAL','SCAL'],
                ['Shared Svc','Shared Svc'],
            ],
            lazyRender: true,
            listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
        }
    }, {
        id:'losPlanCodes',
        header: 'LOS Plan Name',
        dataIndex: 'losPlanCodes',
        width: 250,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            tooltip: 'losPlanName',
            selectOnTab: true,
            store: planStore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            lazyRender: true,
            multiSelect: true,
            displayField: 'planName',
            valueField:'planId'
        }
    }, {
        id:'losLocationCodes',
        header: 'LOS Location',
        dataIndex: 'losLocationCodes',
        width: 90,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            selectOnTab: true,
            autoSelect: true,
            store: locationStore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            multiSelect: true,  
            lazyRender: true,
            valueField:'locAreaId',
            displayField: 'locAreaName',
            listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
            //value: 'losLocationCodes',
            //data : 'losLocationCodes',
            /*
            listeners : {
                'beforeselect' : function(combo, record,index){
                },
                'change': function(combo, newValue, oldValue){
                },
                'afterrender': function(combo, record1) {
                }
            }
        */
        }
    },{
        id: 'Entity',
        header: 'entity',   
        dataIndex: 'entity',
        width: 30,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } , {
        id: 'locationCode',
        header: 'Location Code',
        dataIndex: 'locationCode',
        width: 50,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'deptId',
        header: 'Dept Code',
        dataIndex: 'deptId',
        width: 50,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    } ,{
        id: 'deptName',
        header: 'Dept Name',
        dataIndex: 'deptName',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            disabled: true
        }
    }],
    selModel: {
        selType: 'cellmodel'
        //selType: 'checkboxmodel'
    },
    renderTo: 'editor-grid',
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Select All'
    }],
    plugins: [
      Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
          clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
          pluginId: 'employeeEditing',
          autoCancel: false,    
          listeners: {
          'beforeedit': function(editor, e, eOpts) {

         //  alert(editor.rowIdx)
         //    alert(editor.field)
         //   alert(editor.value)

            if (editor.record.get('entity') == 2 || editor.record.get('entity') == 02){
                   grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losPlanCodes').disable();
                   grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losLocationCodes').disable();
            } else if (editor.record.get('entity') == 8 || editor.record.get('entity') == 08){
                    grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losPlanCodes').disable();                        
            }
            /*
                var me = this;
                this.isEditAllowed = false;
                this.cancelEdit();
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'Not Allowed to Edit',
                    msg: 'Not Allowed to Edit this record with entity'+ this.entity,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            return true;
            */
          },
         'cancelEdit': function(editor) {
                grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losPlanCodes').enable();
                grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losLocationCodes').enable();
          },
          'validateedit': function(e) {

          },
          'edit': function(editor) {
                if (editor.record.get('entity') == 2 || editor.record.get('entity') == 02){
                           grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losPlanCodes').enable();
                           grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losLocationCodes').enable();
                        }
                else if (editor.record.get('entity') == 8 || editor.record.get('entity') == 08){
                        grid.getPlugin('employeeEditing').editor.form.findField('losPlanCodes').enable();                        
                }
         }
        }
      })
  ],
  listeners: {
          'render': function(grid) {
          }
      }
});
grid.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', this.onSelectChange, this);
```

Please help

][1]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are setting the value of the combobox BEFORE its data is loaded. Review the order of the events, try to use a callback for when the store has loaded, and setting its value after that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured this out by now, but in case not, you need a custom `renderer` on the column config to pluck the displayfield out, i.e:

```
{
    id:'losPlanCodes',
    header: 'LOS Plan Name',
    dataIndex: 'losPlanCodes',
    width: 250,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        tooltip: 'losPlanName',
        selectOnTab: true,
        store: planStore,
        queryMode: 'local',
        lazyRender: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        displayField: 'planName',
        valueField:'planId'
    },
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, view) {
        return planStore.getById(value).get('planName');
    }
},
```